# Permission rebuild fail

Tags: 7, domain-access

My Drupal 7 site is upgraded from Drupal 6. When I install the Domain Access (not installed with Drupal 6) module, I need to rebuild permissions.

I tried rebuilding them from the administrative pages, but it fails; I tried doing it with Drush, but it failed again.

```
drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'
```

I can't find any information in watchdog and PHP logs.

Does anyone know why it happens, or how I can fix this?

Comment: What indication do you get that it failed? Any messages at all? Or it just asks you to rebuild again?

Comment: @Rylyn did you get solution to this problem?

Comment: Check apache/php error logs, usually you get no messages or watchdog log if the error caused you Application/Drupal website to stop before reporting it. if there is any issue you should be able to view it from the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem (Rebuild Permissions failing) and tracked it to Organic groups.

1. Go to Administration > Configuration > Organic groups > OG field settings
2. Under **Bundles** select the **Group** content type
3. Under **Fields** select **Group visibility**
4. Click **Add field**